# Scale ECS Task by open network connections?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

We have a service that connects to a database. The memory and CPU consumption is overall quite low.

However, we find we're running out of concurrent requests with, say, one container. Scaling to 2+ allows more throughput.

What metric, if any, can we latch onto to autoscale based on concurrent requests? I think they're handles, but I'm out of my lane a bit there.

Comment: Are you using a load balancer?

Comment: yup, we have an ALB in front of this service

Answer (score 1):

I would look into using your load balancer's `RequestCount` or `ActiveConnectionCount` [metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html) as your auto-scaling trigger.